# Parsys on top of an image

Tags: image, aem

There is requirement where parsys should be added on top of an image. It is like a background image with the provision of parsys so that other components can be dragged and dropped on top of it. I am using html5smartimage for image component. But, no clue yet on how I can get the parsys on top of the image. Please help if you find any ideas. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is the image authorable?  If so, how do you intend to provide click-area for the authors to change the image vs edit items in the parsys.

If the image isn't authorable, just target the CSS for your parsys and set the image.

If the image is authorable, in edit mode you want the image to be distinct from the parsys and have separate clickable areas.  Then in preview/disabled modes you would generate the actually desired markup & CSS to position the parsys content over the background image.